ASP.NET Core with Azure AD auth infinite redirect loop when the app is hosted in AWS ECS Fargate with multiple tasks
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 app integrated with Azure AD for authentication. It is hosted in AWS ECS using Fargate and the authentication works without any issues when there is only one ECS task running.
But, if I bump up the ECS task count to 2 and then launch the app, it goes on a infinite redirect loop.
Here is the code from Program.cs
builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

I tried to use AddInMemoryTokenCaches(), but that did not work and it seems to be used for persisting token to call any downstream Web API's.

It sounds like you need to enable sticky sessions for your load balancer. Also, did you see this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73418098/asp-net-6-azure-ad-authentication-infinite-redirect-loops-with-aws-network-lb-a?rq=2

Thank you @MarkB, I managed to solve this problem by adding Data protection that can be shared by multiple instances.

I have managed to solve this problem by adding Data protection that can be shared by both the tasks.
builder.Services
        .AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToDbContext<MyDbContext>();

I have used the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore for storing data protection keys to Database.
